# Why L.vectorGrid.protobuf return undefined?

Tags: leaflet, react

I have this component:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMap } from 'react-leaflet';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { selectLayersStatus } from './LayerSlice';

type LayerDetails = {
    layerName?: string;
    tileUrl?: string;
    fillColor?: string;
} | undefined;

const AddLayerToMap: React.FC<LayerDetails> = () => {

    const selectLayersStatusSelector = useSelector(selectLayersStatus);

    const mapInstance = useMap();


    useEffect(() => {

        console.log('selectLayersStatusSelector:', selectLayersStatusSelector?.layers);

        let layerName: any = selectLayersStatusSelector?.layers?.data?.layerName;
        let tileUrl: any = selectLayersStatusSelector?.layers?.data?.tileUrl;
        let fillColor: any = selectLayersStatusSelector?.layers?.data?.fillColor;

        const defaultOptions: any = {
            zIndex: 1,
            // fetchOptions: {
            //     headers: {
            //       'Authorization': `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`
            //     }
            //   },
            maxZoom: 18,
            minZoom: 5,
            rendererFactory: 'L.canvas.tile',
            attribution: 'SIGEO',
        };

        const newGridConfig: any = {
            url: tileUrl,
            layerName: layerName,
            vectorTileLayerStyles: {
                default: {
                    weight: 1,
                    fillColor: fillColor,
                    fillOpacity: 0.3,
                    fill: true,
                }
            },
            interactive: true,
            getFeatureId: (f: any) => f.name,
        }

        if (mapInstance) {

            console.log('tileUrl:', tileUrl);
            console.log('layerName:', layerName);
            console.log('fillColor:', fillColor);

            console.log("AddLayerToMap: ", tileUrl, layerName, mapInstance);

            console.log("mapInstance: ", mapInstance);
            console.log("Adding new vector grid layer: ", newGridConfig);

            // @ts-ignore
            const addedLayer = L.vectorGrid?.protobuf(newGridConfig?.url,
                { ...defaultOptions, ...newGridConfig?.options })?.addTo(mapInstance);

            console.log("Added new vector grid layer: ", addedLayer);

        }

    }, [mapInstance, selectLayersStatusSelector?.layers]);

    // ... (rest of the functions and event handlers remain the same)

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}

export default AddLayerToMap;
```

And I have this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "map-fe",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.14",
    "@mui/material": "^5.14.14",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^6.16.2",
    "@react-leaflet/core": "^2.1.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.59",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.13",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "keycloak-js": "^22.0.4",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet.vectorgrid": "^1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-leaflet-vectorgrid": "^2.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.7"
  }
}
```

Why the last `console.log("Added new vector grid layer: ", addedLayer);` return `undefined`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with these imports:

```
import L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.vectorgrid/dist/Leaflet.VectorGrid.bundled.js';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

And this:

```
// @ts-ignore
addedLayer = new L.VectorGrid.Protobuf(newGridConfig.url, { ...defaultOptions, ...newGridConfig.options }).addTo(mapInstance);
```